# Should I use CDATA in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What difference does this make:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ ...code
```

Compared to this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ...code
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "What is the best practice regarding X?" question.  See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use XHTML 1.0 anymore ( which is where you would use CDATA ). What is even more important, you should no have javascript inside your html files. Instead you should include external files via `<script src="/my/js/file.js"></script>`.

Comment: To not use XHTML is just your personal opinion. The next version would be HTML 5, which is still far from being final: http://ishtml5readyyet.com/

Comment: @Guffa , while you should not use all the features of HTML5 , using HTML5 doctype is strongly recommended.

Comment: And core HTML 5 support is available in most browsers at this point, whether all the fringe features are available or not.  The same can't be said for XHTML; most browsers parse XHTML as HTML anyway, or skip all the features of XHTML that make it worthwhile (namely strict validation).

Comment: you should not server XHTML as text/html .. it's just wrong.

Comment: As a side note, while it's true most of the time, it's not *always* a better idea to use external JS.  If the file is small enough, placing it inline can reduce server requests for a speed boost.

Answer (score 3):

If you use XHTML it's useful to have CDATA tags in the script to make the page pass validation.

Normally it's not needed for the page to work. Browsers just look for the end tag of the script and assume that everything in the script tag should be used as is, without decoding.

Comment: If you use XHTML, it's *all but required* to have CDATA tags.  (It's definitely required if you have `<` or `&` in your script.  Otherwise, i forget.)  Any conforming XML parser would choke on the typical script that's not wrapped in a CDATA tag.  That it works, when and if it does, is purely due to XHTML being crappily supported and the browser parsing it as HTML.  Which defeats the main goals of XHTML in the first place.